# Interpolation on curvilinear grid

Tags: coordinate-systems, data-analysis

How could someone interpolate spatial data on a curvilinear grid, like the one in the picture shown?

[image]

Comment: What do you know about interpolating onto any grid? Have you tried anything?

Comment: Do you know a set of appropriate orthogonal functions for the task?

Comment: @tpg2114 I know about bi-linear and tri-linear interpolation onto a regular Cartesian mesh grid. I also understand how spline interpolation works. However ,based on bi-linear interpolation, I cannot understand how I would find the value of a function f at the point f(r0,theta0) knowing the values of f at every node on the grid. Would I just use weights for nearest neighbors?

Answer (score 0):

In Matlab, you can use [scatter interpolation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatteredinterpolant.html). However, once I asked ChatGPT to write a code for me, but it was using some functions from the libraries come with ["Numerical recipe" book.](http://numerical.recipes/) You can also use [griddata](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/griddata.html) in Matlab, but I think, scatter interpolation is faster for repetitive interpolation. If you are interested in Python, take a look at [this (N-D curver or N-D scatter).](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/tutorial/interpolate.html)